# why i lose viewParam value?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, parameters, navigation, nullpointerexception

I have AAA.jsf page with link:

```
<h:link value="To BBB" outcome="BBB">
  <f:param name="id" value="10"/>
</h:link>
```

BBB.jsf:

```
<html>
 <h:body>
   <f:metadata>
      <f:viewParam name="id"/>
   </f:metadata>
   <h:form>
     <h:outputText value="#{bean.id}"/> 

     <h:commandButton value="Make some logic.." action="bean.doSomething"/>
   </h:form>
 </h:body>
</html>
```

Bean.class:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
class Bean{
  public String getId(){
    Map<String,String> param = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    return param.get("id");
  }

  public void doSomething(){
    //do some logic....
    //I don't use id parameter
  }
}
```

After I get from AAA page to BBB page and click on "Make some logic.." button all code from `doSomething()` method is run. When this method end and i return from I get NullPointerException because i have to get `id` param in `getId()` method. This mean that i lose viewParam `id`. Why?

**Edit**

Related issue:
[lose view page parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895454/lose-view-page-parameter)

Comment: Do you use the param in doSomething method ?

Comment: No, i don't use it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the commandButton,  the form is submitted using HTTP POST and if you check the URL, it doesn't contain the parameter id in it.

In your `f:metadata` tag, specify a value attribute to bind the param to a bean attribute. You can then use the value in your beans using the same bean attribute.

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.value}/>
</f:metadata>
```

In your bean, define a new variable to set the value of Id and also provide its getter and setter methods.

**OR**

Use the f:param in your commandButton to have access to the parameter after submit.

```
<h:commandButton value="Make some logic.." action="bean.doSomething">
  <f:param name="id" value="10"/>
<h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Can i do this without save parameter value in bean?